# Concrete classes with abstract type members

Tags: scala, types

Given the following traits and class. Why does this compile? Can this be actually used for something?

```
trait Container {
  type A
}

trait AnotherContainer[B]{
    def x(b : B) : B
}

trait Mixed extends Container with AnotherContainer[Container#A]

class Impl extends Mixed{
    def x(a : Container#A) = a 
}

new Impl().x _

scala> new Impl().x _
res0: (Container#A) => Container#A = <function>
```

**Update:**

```
class Baz { type T; }
```

Is actually a feature but I could not find the motivation for it: [#1753](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/1753).

Comment: Why? B in the instance of AnotherContainer in Mixed is A, so the signature for x is consistent between AnotherContainer.x and Impl.x. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Randall Well, `type A` is abstract, and I don't see it becoming concrete anywhere. So I'd expect `Impl` not to compile, returning a "needs to be abstract" error.

Comment: It's intentional that this is allowed; see https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1753 for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks harmless if useless to me.  The type that x wants doesn't exist, so you can't pass it to the method.  Whether harmless uselessness should be a compile-time error is a matter of taste, I suppose.

If you look at what x actually does, it decompiles thusly:

```
public java.lang.Object x(java.lang.Object);
  Code:
   0:   aload_1
   1:   areturn
```

which is exactly what the identity method should do (load the argument regardless of type, return it).  You can write something equivalent with much less code:

```
trait AbstractType { type T }
class Useless extends AbstractType { def identity(t: AbstractType#T) = t }
```

Except nothing has type AbstractType#T, so again we have uselessness.

Unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, the compiler adds the default type bounds of `>: Nothing <: Any`. The second example below shows a case where an abstract type becomes usable (if not useful).

```
scala> trait T { type A >: Nothing <: Any }
defined trait T

scala> 1: T#A
<console>:6: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: T#A
       1: T#A
       ^

scala> trait T { type A >: Int <: Int }
defined trait T

scala> 1: T#A                          
res6: T#A = 1

scala> "": T#A
<console>:6: error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.lang.String("")
 required: T#A
       "": T#A
       ^
```

Comment: `trait T { type A >: Int <: Int }` is just a complicated way to define `trait T { type A = Int }` the result is the the same.